# Objective C: Comparing CGPoints

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, if-statement

I am trying to do an if-else statement for my CGPoints 
how would I be able to do that, I tried this code...

```
if (point1 != point2)
{
       //statement
}
```

I'm having this error

`Invalid operand for binary expression...`

Thanks!

Comment: point1 and point2 is a operand which is user defined type(structure) and != is a operator. Here compiler get confuse in operand type as compiler only can accept pointer type and int float char etc as a operand.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try to use function `CGPointEqualToPoint` instead.

```
if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(p1,p2))
{
  //statement
}
```

Comment: is this also applicable for dropping items on a particular area? because i'll use it for that example too.:)

Comment: @Ramiro - read the CGGeometry reference link I included in my answer.  It should many of these type of questions.

Answer (score 8):

you can do:

```
if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(point1, point2)) {
....
}
```

floats (and therefore CGFloats) are a bit tricky because sometimes you want them to be considered equal, but they're a tiny margin off. if you want a "fuzzy" comparison, you could do something like:

```
if (fabsf(point1.x - point2.x) > 0.0001f || fabsf(point1.y - point2.y) > 0.0001f) {
...
}
```

this checks to see if the x & y components of point1 and point2 are different by an amount greater than 0.0001 (a totally arbitrary number, can be whatever you want depending on your desired accuracy).

Answer (score 7):

I would advice to use following function: (from Apple Docs)

**CGPointEqualToPoint** : *Returns whether two points are equal.*

```
bool CGPointEqualToPoint (CGPoint point1, CGPoint point2);
```

> > Parameters
> >
> > point1 : The first point to examine.
> >
> > point2 : The second point to examine.
> >
> > Return Value true if the two specified points are the
> >     same; otherwise, false.

For more information read here: [CGGeometry Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 5):

see **CGPointEqualToPoint:** Returns whether two points are equal.

```
bool CGPointEqualToPoint (
   CGPoint point1,
   CGPoint point2
);
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html

**Parameters**

- point1: The first point to examine.
- point2: The second point to examine.

**Return Value**

true if the two specified points are the same; otherwise, false.